# How to specify a range of type Int when using an NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to retrieve some Core Data data between two days of type `Int`.
I am currently using something like this, which crashes my app:

```
static func rangePredicate(startDay: Int, endDay: Int) -> NSPredicate {
    return NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %d && %K <= %d", #keyPath(MyModel.day), startDay, endDay)
}
```

What is the correct way to specify the range ?

Comment: You can compare the dates ?

Comment: It crashes because you have 4 placeholders but only 3 parameters

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to fix it with the following:

```
return NSPredicate(format: "%K BETWEEN {%d, %d}", #keyPath(StepUpModel.day), startDay, endDay)
```